# Pathview R: Mapping known transcripts to a KEGG pathway diagram representing FoldChange

Tags: r

I'm struggling with: library(pathview)

I have a data frame ("T3") with the following column names and possible identifiers to map Fold changes to a significantly enriched KEGG pathway:

KEGGid SYMBOL   Human_ENSEMBL   Human_ENTREZID  Mouse_ensembl_gene_id   Mouse_ENTREZID

It has taken a long time to learn how to get all of these possible IDs but unfortunately, when I try to map them to relevant KEGG nodes, by assigning identifiers as rownames, I do not seem to yield a result (Error message:

Warning: None of the genes or compounds mapped to the pathway!
Argument gene.idtype or cpd.idtype may be wrong.
Error in select(db.obj, keys = in.ids, keytype = in.type, columns = c(in.type,  : 
  unused arguments (keys = in.ids, keytype = in.type, columns = c(in.type, out.type))
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "labels", value = c("", "", "", "",  : 
  replacement has 82 rows, data has 89
)

This is frustrating because T3 contains all of the transcripts which are annotated to PI3K signaling and so they should map. None of the identifiers which I have been using seem to work? However, I know that these transcripts map. For example using "AKT3", which is in the list, we can highlight this node online [https://www.genome.jp/kegg-bin/show_pathway?hsa04151+10000]  Where the +1000 at the end of the address specifies AKT node to be highlighted in red.

Command lines for example

```
SYMBOL <- c("AKT3", "AKT3")
Human_ENSEMBL<- c("ENSG00000117020","ENSG00000275199")
Human_ENTREZID <-c("10000", "10000")
Mouse_ensembl_gene_id <- c("ENSMUSG00000019699", "ENSMUSG00000019699")
Mouse_entrezgene <- c(23797, 23797)
log2FoldChange <-c(-0.676668324, -0.676668324)


T3 <- c(SYMBOL, Human_ENSEMBL, Human_ENTREZID, Mouse_ensembl_gene_id, 
Mouse_entrezgene, log2FoldChange)

row.names(T3) <- T3$SYMBOL ##For example here using SYMBOL but I have tried a 
lot of the other identifiers

pv.out <- pathview(gene.data = T3, 
pathway.id = "hsa04151", 
out.suffix = "Control vs Treatment"     )
```

Thanks for taking the time to help

Mark

Comment: I see error messages but no code or data-objects. Just asking for help on an error message but not providing the needed means of debugging is not acceptable on SO. Such questions get closed. You should use the [edit] facitlies to improve your question. I really hope you do so. I'm interested helping on this topic if I can. I think that you spelled the Bioc package name incorrectly. R is case-sensitive.

Comment: At the moment the `T3` object is only a 12 item character vector, so treating it like a dataframe is going to fail. I also see no use of the `select` function which was throwing the error.